# Match regular expression not containing bad words

Tags: php, regex, pcre

How to make a preg_match pass when the subject does not contain bad words? This is doing the inverse:

```
$pattern = '/\b(some|bad|words)\b/i';

function matches($pattern, $value) {
    echo "matches $pattern: $value, matches: " . preg_match($pattern, $value)."\n";
}

matches($pattern, "This should match");
matches($pattern, "This bad string should not match");
```

All examples I found so far do the opposite: they match when subject contains bad words.

I want it to match when it does not contain bad words.

Tried several combinations and searches, but could not find a solution. Using '?!' with '\b' seems to be not possible?

Comment: `if(!preg_match(.....))` - simple.

Comment: We have a 4GL tool written in PHP that allows specifying a 'validationPattern' attribute, in which we cannot invert the outcome. Thanks anyhow for your suggestion.

Comment: The only reason to use the match function is to actually match something. If you don't want to match some words, well, what words do you want to match ?

Answer (score 0):

```
^((?!\b(some|bad|words)\b).)*$
```

Answer (score -1):

**You can use this**

```
^((?!some|bad|words).)*$
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/FzBmh4/1/)

Comment: Thanks for your reaction. This actually also matches partial words, like someday or badly. This pattern was the solution (based on answer in 'marked as duplicate' question):  `/^(?:(?!\b(some|bad|words)\b).)*$/i`

Comment: @KeesvanDieren your regex will match `o'some;` use `space` instead of `\b`